# asp.net site dying as it starts up for unknown reason that I think has to do with VS 2010RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Environment:
Win 7x64, VS 2010 RC, Resharper 5 beta, MVC2 RC, git

When I reboot my machine, my website, configured in IIS, seems to be fine.  As soon as I load VS, and try and debug from it, the site becomes completely unresponsive.  I can't even get it to serve images.  I have the website in IIS pointed directly to the folder with my web project in it, so that I can debug easily.

At this point, closing VS doesn't help.  Neither does resetting IIS (stop/start World Wide Publishing Service).  Killing the Intellitrace process doesn't help either.

The site was working ok until pretty recently.  Strangely, it initially seemed to be a sporadic bug, and now it's constant.

As for what I have to go on, I have the following things being logged to the application event log.  They're in this order, which means the bottom ones happened first:

.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4927 - Failed to CoCreate profiler.
TraceLog Profiler failed initialization, process w3wp.exe
The TraceLog Profiler in process w3wp.exe failed to get configuration from the logger.  (w3wp.3xe)

---

Closing Visual Studio at this point yields the following two additional events:

---

Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards.

DETAIL - 
 1 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-82-781516728-2844361489-696272565-2378874797-2530480757_Classes:
Process 7060 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools\IntelliTrace.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-781516728-2844361489-696272565-2378874797-2530480757_CLASSES

---

Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards.

DETAIL -   2 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-82-781516728-2844361489-696272565-2378874797-2530480757: Process 7060 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools\IntelliTrace.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-781516728-2844361489-696272565-2378874797-2530480757 Process 7060 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
10.0\Team Tools\TraceDebugger Tools\IntelliTrace.exe) has opened key \REGISTRY\USER\S-1-5-82-781516728-2844361489-696272565-2378874797-2530480757\Control Panel\International

---

I've removed everything from the  tag in my web.config.  I'm out of ideas.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "I've removed everything from the tag in my web.config"? Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a repair on your IIS, .NET Framework, or VS2010 installs?